well defined morphism, Okonek's appendix, Sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$ and problems in linear algebra.
I am currently trying to complete the details of the appendix 'sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$ and problems of linear algebra' found in the Okonek's book  'vector bundles on complex projective space'. I'm stuck on some details in section 2.2.
Let me be precise. Let $\theta$ be the  $n+1$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Set $\Lambda:=\Lambda(\theta)$ to be their exterior (grassman) algebra and define $\mathcal{M}^b(\Lambda)$ the category of all $\Lambda$-graded modules with finite number of generators, i.e, $\dim(V)<\infty$ for every $V\in \mathcal{M}^b(\Lambda)$.
On the other hand let $V=\bigoplus V_j \in \mathcal{M}^b(\Lambda)$ and consider $L_j(V):=\mathcal{V}_j \otimes \mathcal{O}(j)$ with $\mathcal{V}_j$
the constant sheaf with fiber $V_j$. Fix a basis $\xi_0,..,\xi_n$  in $\theta$, and a basis $x_0,...,x_n$ in the dual space $\theta^*$. Clearly we have a  morphisms
$\xi_i\colon \mathcal{V}_j\to \mathcal{V}_{j+1},\quad x_i\colon \mathcal{O}(j)\to \mathcal{O}(j+1)$
We put $ \partial_j:=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\xi_i\otimes x_i\colon L_j(V)\to L_{j+1}(V)$. Im stuck on proving that $\partial_j$ does not depend of choice of basis $\xi_0,...,\xi_n$. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks all.

Isn't this just linear algebra? You can work it out by writing the change of basis matrix explicitly.

surely it is but I couldn't fill the details.

Let $ \gamma_0, \ldots, \gamma_n $ be another basis and $ y_0, \ldots, y_n $ its dual basis. If $ \gamma_i = \sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{ij} \xi_{j} $ and $ y_i = \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_{ij} x_j $ then a short calculation shows that the change of basis matrices $ A = (a_{ij}) $ and $ B = (b_{ij}) $ are related by $ A.B^T = I $.
Then $ \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma_i \otimes y_i = \sum_{i=0}^n (\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{ij} \xi_{j}) \otimes (\sum_{k=0}^{n} b_{ik} x_k) = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} ( \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{ij}b_{ik} ) \xi_j \otimes x_k  $
The sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{ij}b_{ik} $ is $ (B^T.A)_{kj} $ by definition. So it is $ 0 $ if $ j \neq k $ and $ 1 $ if $ j = k $.
So $ \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma_i \otimes y_i = \sum_{j=0}^n \xi_j \otimes x_j $
